# I want to create a form that cannot be manipulated

Tags: php, forms

I have created form for online shopping cart website customer adds products to his bag and checks out filling customer information in that page testing people use some tampering techniques and able to change the price of the product before validating the data to MD5 secure hash they are saying they able to tamper the price as we are using live data form how to fix this problem if code is required will provided

Many thanks for your answers
Vasu

Comment: Let's say that the customer has kept the cart items for a week and, meanwhile, the prices have raised. Is it okay to lose the difference?

Answer (score 5):

> and able to change the price of the product before validating the data

The solution to this is to take only the *number* of products ordered from the form, and to do the price calculation internally, on server side. If necessary, every time the cart gets updated.

Anything calculated on client side is never trustworthy.

While you're at it, make sure that you don't run into the next bug opportunity on the way: Make sure users can't enter fractions when specifying the number of items, like `0.1` - leading to 10% of the original price. :)

Comment: Or negative numbers. Say they order -1 of an apple which costs 10 euro, you dont want to pay them ;)

Comment: @TJHeuvel oh boy, yeah! That would be fun, too - especially if automatically connected to a PayPal account :)

Comment: From now on I'm going to try to order 0.51 items in every online shop :) THere's always a chance they calculate the price before any rounding takes place ;P

Answer (score 2):

Upon checkout, recalculate all the prices on the server side again based on valid/rounded quantities. Display a non-editable confirmation page to the user before proceeding to charge the payment instrument. If the user disagrees with the confirmation, he can go back to the cart and make changes.

Answer (score 1):

When the form is submitted, calculate the price of the items in the shopping basket and compare it to the price submitted by the browser.

If they differ, ask the user to confirm the real price.

Comment: Why should the client be responsible to give the right price. It is website itself that should decided that.

Comment: @ElGabbu there's nothing wrong with asking the user to confirm the real price. A price might have changed in the database during the user's visit, for example.

Comment: If you are displaying the price to the user, and something goes wrong (which is unlikely, an attack is more likely) then asking them to confirm the real price is a lot safer (legally speaking) then billing them for a different price.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Pekka. The price itself should not be part of the form. The only thing that should be submitted is the qty ordered link to the product_id. Price calculation should be done on the server after form submission.